# How to test my custom kernel without breaking my phone?

Tags: android, linux, testing, kernel

i am currently building my first kernel build...

I am afraid of flashing it on my phone as it could be broken

How can I test if the kernel works before flashing it?

I have a Oneplus One.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unlock bootloader first then you can boot your kernel instead of installed kernel  by using fastboot tool, Please follow below steps

```
1) Install full Android SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download
2)fastboot oem unlock //unlock bootloader to boot custom kernel
3)fastboot reboot
4)fastboot boot linux/arch/arm/boot/zImage ramdisk //boot custom kernel with ramdisk
```

For detail instruction refer [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2788632) thread